# Getting reference of the front element when queue is popped

Tags: c++

I'm playing with some examples to decide whether it is safe to use the reference to the front of the queue when I know it is going to be popped later.

```
queue<int> q;
q.push(5);
q.push(2);
int & a = q.front(); // a = 5 now
q.pop();
q.push(123);
cout << a << "\n"; // a = 5 now
```

This example makes it look like it is safe.

```
queue<int> q;
q.push(5);
int & a = q.front(); // a = 5 now
q.pop();
q.push(123);
cout << a << "\n"; // a = 123 now
```

This example makes me realize I probably have to make a copy of the front element instead of using a reference. However, I do not understand the behavior discrepancy between the two examples. Shouldn't the second example variable "a" also be 5? Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: You are invoking *undefined behavior*  by reading from a dangling reference (since the element `a` is referring to no longer is in the queue)

Comment: @UnholySheep I see. That makes sense.

Comment: For reference regarding @dfri's comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque#Invalidation_notes

Comment: @dfri: The element is *gone*, it's not just a reallocation based invalidation of the reference. If this were a stack, then yes, the element would still exist (it was never removed), but it's a queue, the `pop` *removed* it, it didn't just potentially relocate it. Your mistake is thinking of `push` and `pop` as referring to the same end of the queue, but `queue`'s `push` is equivalent to `push_back` and `pop` to `pop_front` on the underlying `deque`. There is no `5` at all.

Comment: @dfri I'm not exactly sure what you are referring to, `q.pop` removes the "5" from the `queue`, this shouldn't have anything to do with invalidation of references, which AFAIK only applies to references to elements that are in the queue

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes you are right, as specifically specified in [\[deque.modifiers\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/deque.modifiers#4): _"An erase operation that erases the first element of a deque but not the last element invalidates only iterators and references to the erased elements. [...] [ Note: `pop_­front` and `pop_­back` are erase operations.  — end note ]"_.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

As governed by [[deque.modifiers]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/deque.modifiers#4) [**emphasis** mine]:

> ```
> iterator erase(const_iterator position);
> iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
> void pop_front();
> void pop_back();
> ```
>
> *Effects:* An erase operation that erases the last element of a deque invalidates only the past-the-end iterator and all iterators and
> references to the erased elements. **An erase operation that erases
> the first element of a deque but not the last element invalidates only
> iterators and references to the erased elements.** An erase operation
> that erases neither the first element nor the last element of a deque
> invalidates the past-the-end iterator and all iterators and references
> to all the elements of the deque. [ *Note:* **`pop_­front` and
> `pop_­back` are erase operations.**  — *end note* ]

The effects of invoking `pop()` on a `std::queue` object is as if invoking `pop_front()` on a `std::deque` object. Thus, storing a reference to the `front()` of a `std::queue` object, say stored as `ref_front`, followed by invocation of `pop()` on the queue object invalidates the `ref_front` reference.

```
queue<int> q;
q.push(5);
int & a = q.front();
q.pop();              // invalidates reference 'a'
// ... reading 'a' invokes undefined behaviour
```

Thus, both your examples invokes undefined behaviour, [demons may fly out of your nose](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.std.c/c/ycpVKxTZkgw/m/S2hHdTbv4d8J) and any kind of analysis of your program beyond this point will be a fruitless exercise.